# ¿Porque no puedo instalar Google.Apis en Package Manager?

Tags: c#, nuget

Trato de instalar Google.Apis pero no me permite instalarlo me sale este mensaje 
¿alguien que pueda ayudarme?

```
PM> Install-Package Google.Apis -Version 1.30.0
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Google.Apis.Core (≥ 1.30.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Net.Http (≥ 4.3.1)'.
Install-Package : 'System.Net.Http' already has a dependency defined for 'System.IO'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Google.Apis -Version 1.30.0
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

Me ocurrio este error una vez y pude resolver ese error actualizando NuGet Package Manager [descargandolo la pagina oficional](https://www.nuget.org/downloads). Busca la version del visual studio que estas utilizando(probablemente 15 para abajo ya que en el 2017 esta incluido por defecto) y descargalo para esa version.

Tambien puedes intentarlo haciendo los siguientes pasos:

1. Abre el cmd(command line)
2. En el cmd navega a la carpeta de tu proyecto y busca una sub-carpeta llamada  **.nuget** y accede a ella. Por ejemplo: `C:\> cd c:/proyectos/miaplicacion/.nuget`
3. Por ultimo ejecuta el siguiente commando en la consola: `nuget update -self`

Esto actualizara nuget.

O tambien puedes actualizarlo haciendo lo siguiente:

```
Herramientas -> Extensiones y Actualizaciones -> Instalado
```

Alli buscas a Nuget y lo actualizas.